# Tomcat JVM - which memory parameter to increase after Heap Memory Statistics

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, heap-memory

I am having

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Which parameters would you increase for the Tomcat after knowing the following Heap Memory Statistics?

Heap Memory Statistics

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter that defines maximum heap size is `-Xmx` but **do not simply change it without knowing the reason you run out of memory**! Apart from it there are many other parameters that influence how your memory is structured and garbage collected.

To give you a simple analogy, it's like a bucket of water. It can only fit given amount of water. If you **know** you need more water, you can get a bigger bucket. But if you are constantly pouring more water into it than you consume, the size of the bucket does not matter - it will fill up sooner or later. In programing this is called memory leak.

That is why you should not simply increase heap size. You need to do some analysis to understand why you are running out of memory and if adding more memory would solve the problem or simply postpone it. Now to do perform those analysis exactly is by far too broad question to be answered here.

Comment: I agree it is too broad if you don't see the context and don't have further analysis. Unfortunately I don't have access to monitor the running server. Maybe 1 important point would also be to keep -Xms equal to -Xmx...